# Code is working from eclipse but not from jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, batch-file, pgp

I have created a maven project. It has one functionality of decrypting a file using PGP encryption/decryption. When I'm running it from eclipse it's working fine. But when I am running it using a jar file from batch it's not working. Any idea why?

I am creating the jar from eclipse this way-

1. **run as**
2. **maven install**

my bat file code is-

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.7.0_45\bin
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%
java pgp.jar com.pgp.app.latex.PGPApplication >>BatResponse.log
```

Error in log it's displaying is below-

```
 main                2015-08-20 02:40:00,969 ERROR  Got exception while decrypting test.zip.pgp package  due to Cannot run program "gpg" (in directory "D:\Test_ZipFiles"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I think that set PATH=%JAVA_HOME% overrides your previous PATH variable so gpg is not known when running from batchfile, also gpg program and pgp.jar isn't that a name mismatch?

Comment: as @UzorTuTuEjt said - try `set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%` if this is really needed (on my system JAVA_HOME per default settings is within the PATH)

Comment: In your batch you're using `pgp` but the error message says `gpg` -- could there be a typo...?

Comment: actually `pgp` is the jar file name it can be any name where `gpg` is the command name. here we are executing a cmd command. So `gpg` is like `mkdir` in `cmd`.

Comment: The problem resolved but I don't have any user `PATH` variable and my system `Path` variable is `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;` How is it effecting that `gpg` command?